# ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have the following code:

```py
# Construct the set of callbacks
figPath = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.png".format(os.getpid())])
jsonPath = os.path.sep.join([args["output"], "{}.json".format(os.getpid())])
callbacks = [xtrain(figPath, jsonPath=jsonPath), LearningRateScheduler(decay_poly)]
```

Output:

```
callbacks = [xtrain(figPath, jsonPath=jsonPath), LearningRateScheduler(decay_poly)]
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I would really be so grateful for any hints for this problem.

I have no idea. I tried changing the versions of Keras and tensorflow, but ended with the same issues.

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. There's no way to help you, we don't know what any of your variables or functions mean. Given the error, it is likely that either `xtrain` or `LearningRateScheduler` is a NumPy array, rather than the function you expect it to be. Avoid creating variables with the same name as functions you want to use.